# jQuery progressTimer to keep current position from current datetime to goal datetime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this [plugin](https://github.com/nathanhoneycutt/jquery.progressTimer) to add progress bar.

```js
$("#progressTimer").progressTimer({
    timeLimit: 120,
    warningThreshold: 10,
    baseStyle: 'progress-bar-warning',
    warningStyle: 'progress-bar-danger',
    completeStyle: 'progress-bar-info',
    onFinish: function() {
        console.log("I'm done");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-jQuery-Progress-Bar-Timer-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-3-progressTimer/js/jquery.progressTimer.js"></script>

<div id="progressTimer"></div>
```

This is working good. As We know the function is using `timeLimit`.

Now I need to specify `timeLimit` using finish by datetime, example goal to finish datetime is: 15:30:00 from current datetime. So I need the progress bar keep the position by current datetime to finish datetime even if I refresh the page. Is it possible?

I got this [reference](https://github.com/nathanhoneycutt/jquery.progressTimer/pull/2/commits/3535d30e303ca8e0841414d5d20c0df89f78d198), don't know if this is related with my question.

Comment: I fixed your snippet

Comment: What is the event that starts the timer? If pageload from server, you just need to set the end time from the server.

Comment: Hi, start timer is using current datetime to goaltime

Comment: So goaltime has to be the same when the page is reloaded. When do you set the goalTime?

Comment: Yes correct, make it to be `2021-01-02 18:00:00`

Comment: When/Where do you set the goal time??? What is the trigger to start the timer?

Comment: That's why I asked about that. How to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228100/discussion-between-hidayurie-dave-and-mplungjan).

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this

When the page loads, it will see if there already IS a goaltime
If there is, use it, otherwise set it to 15:30 in the future

```
let goalTime = localStorage.getItem("goal") 
if (goalTime) goalTime = +goalTime; // cast to int
else {
  let date = new Date();
  goalTime = date.getTime() + 15*60*60*1000 + 30*60*1000;
  localStorage.setItem("goal",goalTime)
}
const now = new Date().getTime();
const timeLimit = parseInt((goalTime-now)/1000);
if (timeLimit > 0) {
  $("#progressTimer").progressTimer({
    timeLimit: timeLimit,
    warningThreshold: 10,
    baseStyle: 'progress-bar-warning',
    warningStyle: 'progress-bar-danger',
    completeStyle: 'progress-bar-info',
    onFinish: function() {
      console.log("I'm done");
    }
  });
}
```